# Deleting php sessions manually –> PHP throws warning

Tags: php, session-cookies

During some maintenance I have deleted the php user session files. This lead to a behavior that I do not understand. php began to throw errors like this:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(/tmp/sessions/sess_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)
```

I assume that when a user with an old session cookie visits the website, session_start() tries to load the session file but can not find any. The "permission denied" is a bit misleading (the session path is valid and with the right rights).

If the user deletes their browser cookies, everything works again.

My questions: Why does PHP throw a warning in case it can not find the session file? sessions files are cleaned by php regularly, so if a user simply has not been visiting for some time, the cookie might still be transmitted but no session file might be present. But in that case it seems that the warning is not triggered.

How can I prevent PHP to not stop script execution when a warning is issued (rather than a fatal error)?

Comment: _“How can I prevent PHP to not stop script execution when a warning is issued (rather than a fatal error)?”_ - not sure what you mean here; Warnings do not cause fatal errors by themselves. What is the fatal error that you get?

Comment: And which function produces the Warning?

Comment: Why did you manually delete these files? :) Not sure If php stops executing the script when a warning is issued.

Comment: I usually do not manually delete. It just happens so, that I did it and realized the behavior. It's session_start() that produces the warning.